# VirtualBox unable to open VM after update

Tags: virtualbox, 15.10

When trying to open my XP VM with virtual box it says:

```
The device helper structure version has changed.
If you have upgraded VirtualBox recently, please make sure you have
terminated all VMs and upgraded any extension packs. 
If this error persists, try re-installing VirtualBox(VERR_PDM_DEVHLPR3_VERSION_MISMATCH).

Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Wine is also broken.(see my other Question)
If I can't get one of them working I will have to switch to Windows.

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you have a mismatch between extpack and VirtualBox version. One solution is to remove the extpack. On my system you can see the name of the extension pack with this command:

```
andrew@ilium~$ VBoxManage list extpacks
Extension Packs: 1
Pack no. 0:   Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack
Version:      5.0.8
Revision:     103449
Edition:      
Description:  USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 Host Controller, Host Webcam, VirtualBox RDP, PXE ROM, Disk Encryption.
VRDE Module:  VBoxVRDP
Usable:       true 
Why unusable:
```

And then I can uninstall the extpack as follows:

```
andrew@ilium~$ sudo vboxmanage extpack uninstall "Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack"
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Successfully uninstalled "Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack".
```

Try these 2 commands on your own system and then your VM should restart...